# Propagating context with Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I've a Spring Cloud Gateway service with the following security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityApiFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
         // ... additional security config

        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/foo/**")
                .access((authenticationMono, context) -> authenticationMono
                        .flatMap(authentication -> authorizationService.canDo(authentication, FOO, ACCESS))
                        .map(AuthorizationDecision::new));
    }
}
```

`authorizationService.canDo` checks if the user can do the requested action on the requested API. The relevant code:

```
return webClient.get().uri(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(fillHeaders())
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
```

If the user has access, then the request is forwarded to the relevant service.

The response of the access control contains some HTTP headers that I want to add in the request sent to `/api/foo/**`.

I tried to set these headers in the reactor `Context` with `subscriberContext` or adding a `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor`to the webClient. While the context is properly set it's not propagated. The context is lost when I'm in a custom `WebFilter`.

I've added the following code at multiple places with no luck:
`.subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("testContext", "testContextData"));`

I looked at how `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` works and I don't see how it's different from what I'm doing. However, the context is initiated in `ReactorContextWebFilter` which seems to be the first `WebFilter` called. My custom filters are called much later on (after the `canDo` method was called). I did try to find a way to init a context earlier but I can't find anything.

Do we have anyway to have a filter that get called even before `SecurityWebFilterChain`? Or maybe a better solution? The amount of data I could find is limited and I'm new to WebFlux/Reactor.

Spring Security: 5.13.3
Spring Webflux: 2.3.12.RELEASE

Comment: `.subscriberContext` has been deprecated quite a while ago, 

You can set the order of your filters, may be that helps. 

```
       http.addFilter(myFilter-> http.addFilterBefore(myFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION));
        http.addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);
```